# MySQL - Group in a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
doctor_name   |   medicine

John                     a
John                     b
John                     a
John                     b
Kevin                    c
Kevin                    c
Kevin                    c
Kevin                    a
```

I want to group by both `doctor_name` and `medicine`. My desire output is to `SELECT` like this:

```
doctor_name   |   medicine   |   COUNT(medicine)
John                     a             2
John                     b             2
Kevin                    a             1
Kevin                    c             3
```

I don't know how to use normal `GROUP BY` in MySQL to do that. Really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by both `doctor_name` and `medicine`

```
select
doctor_name,
medicine,
count(*) as  total
from table_name
group by doctor_name,medicine
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
doctor_name,
medicine,
count(*) as  total_medicine
FROM table_name
GROUP BY doctor_name,medicine;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query

```
select doctor_name,medicine,count(*) as count
from my_table group by doctor_name,medicine
```